# How to use %?% in sqlite prepared statements for Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Currently my query look like this

```
Cursor c = db.query(CONTENT_TABLE, new String[]{"content"}, "content like %?%", new String[]{keyword}, null, null, null);
```

What i want to do is write a prepared statement, surrounded with the % sign. This is my Logcat

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "%": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT content FROM `const` WHERE content like %?%
```

How do i do this properly?

Comment: You need to quote the string you're searching for, to separate it from the SQL

Comment: does that prevent sql injections?

Comment: Using ? for bind variables prevents injections.  Quoting it is needed for the same reason its needed in Java  or C-  to tell what the sting you're comparing against is and tell it apart from the source code its surrounded by.

Comment: Could you please be clearer a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

i used

```
Cursor c = db.query(CONTENT_TABLE, null, "content like ?", new String[]{"%" + keyword + "%"}, null, null, null);
```

and it worked fine